# Getting account 'locked' status in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, locking, status

I want to unlock one account in SQL Server. Before unlocking I have to check whether that account is locked or not.

I want to unlock only if the account is locked.

Is there any SQL query or stored procedure to get the "Locked" status of SQL user?

Comment: Does your user use SQL or Windows authentication?

Comment: How do you unlock the user once you know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Posting Answer on Behalf of Alex K.

SELECT LOGINPROPERTY('loginname', 'IsLocked')

Comment: This will return `0 (not locked)` or `1 (locked)`

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean a login name that has Login: Denied ? If so you can:

```
SELECT is_disabled from sys.server_principals WHERE name = @loginname
```

Comment: No.. For example if we entered wrong password for a specific MS SQL user more than 3-4 times account gets locked out. I want to check whether a specific account is locked out?

Comment: Ah; SELECT LOGINPROPERTY('loginname', 'IsLocked')

Answer (score 0):

Listing all logins with unlocked statuses in all Databases (active all logins on all DBs)

```
SELECT name, is_disabled, LOGINPROPERTY(name, N'isLocked') as is_locked,
LOGINPROPERTY(name, N'LockoutTime') as LockoutTime into #tmp_is_disabled
FROM sys.sql_logins
WHERE LOGINPROPERTY(name, N'isLocked') = 0    
 
select * from #tmp_is_disabled where is_disabled ='false'
```

~~regarding~~
~~pektas~~