# How to check if user 'sa' (SQL Server) is enable with vb.net

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, vb.net-2010

I would like to know if is possible to check if user 'sa' is enable (SQL Server 2005), but with vb.net.

I tried to find it with this query `select * syslogins`, but here I can´t find it.

Thanks advanced

Please take a look to this screenshot
sa is disable and I get hasaccess = 1
[image: Update 1]

sa is enable and I get hasaccess = 1

[image: Update 2]

Comment: You might try looking at BOL. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178593.aspx Then look at the hasaccess column.

Comment: with hasaccess, I don´t get if sa is enable o disable. I have tried.

Comment: What do you mean by "get if sa is enable o disable"? The value in that column is 1 if it is enabled...assuming you did not install with windows authentication.

Comment: I have the answer from this [SELECT is_disabled from sys.server_principals WHERE name = 'sa'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607290/getting-account-locked-status-in-sql-server) Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

select * from syslogins   I have "sa" in my results.

Are you SURE "Sql Authentication" is enabled for you Sql-Server(Instance)?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

***If Windows Authentication mode is selected during installation, the sa login is disabled. If you later change authentication mode to SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode, the sa login remains disabled. To enable the sa login, use the ALTER LOGIN statement.***

Comment: I know that, but I need to check that with vb.net, becuase it is not enable, I have to enable and create a passwords. But, if is enable, I don´t have to change the passwords.

Comment: @yaqui: Kind of an odd thing to have to do via code, unless you are writing an SSMS clone.

Comment: yes, you're right, this is a little weird ... this is a new user control, and I need to check that. Thanks.